# Counts from many tables into one set of results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot-table

I have multiple tables all with unique product IDs, a user ID and a date.

Is there any way to display a single table to show counts within each table split between each user ID.

I would want one row for each table name and multiple columns for each user id with counts for product IDs within the rows.

For instance:

```
TblName user1 user2 user3
tbl1      1     2     3
tbl2      4     5     6
tbl3      7     8     9
tbl4      3     2     1
```

I feel like this will require Pivot but I'm unsure on how to execute it. Up until this point I've been able to search and find everything I need to build a production database back-end and a functioning front-end user application but this one eludes me.

For some context the requested table is to be used to show production counts for employees across multiple tasks. If possible I'd like to have the date as a parameter for stored procedure so I can create a slider of sorts in the front-end user application.

I've read almost all the similar questions and they either seem to be not what I'm looking for or have gone unresolved or happen to be a request that can't be done. I feel like mine may end up falling in the latter.

I also think I may just be terrible at knowing exactly what to search for to find the answer I'm looking for.

Please let me know if there is any additional information required to fulfill my request.

Comment: Are you sure you want the tables to be rows, and the users to be columns? Presumably there will be a lot of users, and the number of users may vary. But the number of tables is probably small and constant, is it not?

Comment: @allmhuran - While it doesn't really matter i thought that would better. We're a small business, I actually have only 4 users at the moment and that includes me. At most I'd ever have is 10 but I have probably over 14 different production tables for different tasks. The table numbers are more likely to grow than the suspected max users.

Comment: Fair enough, pragmatically. As a point of principle it seems odd to me, the reason is this: changing the number of tables is a schema change, and changing the procedure to handle more tables is also a schema change (if you use the type of union-pivot answer presented below), so those sort of "fit" naturally. Someone is digging into the code to do both changes. Conversely, changing the users is just a data change, which should not require programmer intervention. Since your case is small enough to manage either way, it probably doesn't matter so much.

Comment: You could probably do this using dynamic SQL, although hard-coding things with a UNION might also work.  But I suspect that the reason you're having trouble is that you've chosen a very non-standard way of organizing your data. Putting it all into one table and striping that table by Product ID seems a lot simpler.  If the tables are more or less the same for each product this will be easy to do.  You can always write per-product views against the larger table.

Comment: @ allmhuran - Thank you for your input. Your view is understandable. I am the owner of this business so I should always be here to make the schema changes as necessary. This is a proprietary application but it makes sense that if this were to be a universal application for clients it would need to refrain from changes to the back-end so frequently. Eventually the new tables creation will stop though, the whole database is a work in progress at the moment. once that is complete a dynamic SQL statement for users should take care of any of the other changes necessary.

Comment: @Eric Hirst - I'm definitely new to SQL and databases in general. I do want my data model to be the best that it can be. To explain, each product has to go through step 1 2 and 3 but may only need step 4 or 5 later but never both. Also, it is a production line set up so every step will be done by a different person. Would it make sense to still have 1 table with multiple fields for user and data & time for each step? (7 steps 14 fields)? This was originally done in ms access where it was all 1 table but as we reformatted to a production line it made more sense to split it up.

Comment: @jkfbsc you should Google "3NF" for a clearer picture, but I suspect the simpler data model in your case might have one Product table and another ProductStep table with a foreign key pointing back to the ProductID primary key field in the Product table.  That said, keep it simple and don't expect your users to understand anything about 3NF databases.

Comment: @Eric Hirst - Thanks for this information. It was great read. I can't say I understood all of it and in the end it didn't lead to me changing anything but definitely improved my understanding of normalization. I feel like my database is decently organized as I have no duplicate data other than the product id as primary and foreign keys in each table. I'm sure there's room for improvement but so far the move to SQL has increased speed in every aspect so I'm happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and `union all`

```
select 'table1' as tablename,
       sum(case when userid = 'user1' then 1 else 0 end) as user1,
       sum(case when userid = 'user2' then 1 else 0 end) as user2,
       sum(case when userid = 'user3' then 1 else 0 end) as user3
from table1
union all
select 'table2' as tablename,
       sum(case when userid = 'user1' then 1 else 0 end) as user1,
       sum(case when userid = 'user2' then 1 else 0 end) as user2,
       sum(case when userid = 'user3' then 1 else 0 end) as user3
from table2
union all
. . .;
```

I don't see any advantage in trying to use `pivot` here.  If the users are not known, however, you will need to use dynamic SQL.

Note:  It is usually a sign of a bad data model that stores the same information across multiple tables.  Typically, such information should all be in one table.

Comment: Wow you guys are fast. This is exactly what i was looking for. Worked like a charm. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as I the timer allows. Thanks Gordon.

Comment: To filter this by a date I assume I would just add a when date = @date to each case statement?

Comment: In regards to your note, I originally had it set up to be all one table but everything was being completed by one user and it was in MS access. So as it grew it began to slow down. Also, now we run In a production line setup where each step is a different user. Would it still make sense to have it all in one table with multiple fields for user and date time for each step? (7 steps 14 fields). Keeping in mind that not all production steps are necessary for every product. For instance, step 1 2 and 3 are necessary but it will be either 4 or 5 but never both. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a union pivot approach:

```
SELECT
    TblName,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN userId = 'user1' THEN 1 END) AS user1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN userId = 'user2' THEN 1 END) AS user2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN userId = 'user3' THEN 1 END) AS user3
FROM
(
    SELECT 'tbl1' AS TblName, userId, productId FROM tbl1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tbl2', userId, productId FROM tbl2            UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tbl3', userId, productId FROM tbl3            UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tbl4', userId, productId FROM tbl4
) t
GROUP BY
    TblName;
```